# Mlogit: how to intrepret model adequacy on fitstat

Tags: model, multinomial, mlogit

Two questions regarding mlogit:

1. How exactly do you interpret goodness of fit using fitstat? Is it the R2? or the P-value of LR test?
2. Can the RRR be equated to an odds ratio

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Stata even though it is missing from your tags. Here some comments:

1. I've never used `fitstat`. Regardless, the goodness of fit is treated as usual. You can take a look at the Wald/LR test of your model together with the pseudo-R2.
2. The RRR will be only equivalent to **odds ratios** if the multinomial logit is used when only two classes are available because it collapses into a `logit` specification. If it is not the case, the RRR need to be interpreted with respect to the baseline class (there is where the word ***relative***, from ****relative***-risk ratios (RRR)* comes from).